# Cros Origin + Spring + Angular 4/5

Tags: spring, restful, cors

estou com um problema no meu serviço restful com spring. Mesmo depois de habilitar o CORS, nao consigo conectar com minha aplicação angular.

```
@CrossOrigin
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService service; 

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/lista_todos_usuarios", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Usuario>> buscaTodosUsuarios() {
        Collection<Usuario> usuarios = service.buscaTodosUsuarios();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuarios, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Segue abaixo a mensagem no console do navegador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desculpe a demora (passei uns dias offline). No meu caso utilizei apenas a anotattion @CrossOrigin do spring mesmo. Todavia é possivel pasar parametros para liberar acesso ao serviço, apenas da origem que eu quiser. No meu caso, eu resolvi liberar para qualquer origem (estudo apenas).

Comment: Questão solucionada. Faltava a anotação de @RestController. hehehe